# have SOMEONE do something

Tags: meaning

> 1 If you have someone call you in the middle of the night, it gives you a scare. - Someone calls...

> 2 Jack had Frank translate it for him. - Jack caused Frank to
> translate it for him.

1 and 2 are easy to understand. What about this?

**Today, Jack had one of his students ask a question.**

Does it mean:

Jack caused one of his students to ask a question.

or

Jack was asked a question by one of his students.

Comment: Could mean either. Context might resolve the ambiguity you have correctly noticed. 1. Jack said to a student 'Please ask me a question.' 2. A student said to Jack, 'Where can I find a list of French irregular verbs?'

Comment: Consider *I **had** my phone stolen yesterday*. A perfectly reasonable alternative to *My phone was stolen yesterday* that puts more emphasis on the fact that this happened ***to me*** (so ***I'm*** badly affected; my phone doesn't know or care what happened to it, *but I do*). There's certainly no suggestion that I ***caused*** the theft - quite the opposite, in fact, since using that particular idiomatic format emphasizes the fact that ***I'm a "victim"*** - something [undesirable] was ***done to me***.

Comment: I had my phone STOLEN (3)/Jack had a student ASK (1)

Comment: If you can understand both your first two examples (where #1 implies *[unwanted thing] **happens to subject***, and #2 implies *[wanted thing] **caused by subject***), I don't see what you want from us with your third example. We don't know any more about the context than you do, and you already know the construction is ambiguous, so what are you asking, and why?

Comment: @FumbleFingers My friend in 1970, a motorcycle fan, always wanted to ride a brand-new Triumph Bonneville. He had one for three weeks, and then he had it stolen. Luckily, he told everyone, he had a good insurance policy which completely paid off the credit agreement. And (he told me) a pal who knew some dodgy geezers.

Comment: I knew someone back in the 70s who had his car torched - for real, deliberately, in order to claim on his "Third party, **Fire**, and Theft" insurance. He had another friend (not me! :) set fire to his car while he was in the pub (on the other side of town, in case he needed an alibi to prove *he* didn't do it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - like that old joke about 'I heard you had a fire at your carpet warehouse last week.' -- 'Shhh! it's _next_ week!'

Comment: haha - maybe old to you, but new to me, ty!

Comment: Michael Harvey knows what I want with my 3d example. He answered well.

Comment: @user1425: I still don't understand. Why did you need anything from Michael's first comment? You say *already* understood the difference between your example texts #1 *(**have** someone call you in the middle of the night = **be forced to endure** that unwelcome call)* and #2 *(**had** Frank translate it for him = **made** Frank do that).* Those are contextually obvious (the alternative meanings wouldn't make sense), but with your *Jack had one of his students ask a question* no-one could be sure of the intended  meaning without more context. The words themselves truly are ambiguous.

Comment: I needed a confirmation of my guess about the ambiguity which I was given by Michael.

Answer (score 2):

**"Had"** is quite ambiguous in the sentence:

> Today, Jack **had** one of his students ask a question

It may either mean that Jack made it so that one of his students asked him a question, or that at some point in time a student asked Jack a question and that was what Jack had in result - a question from one of the student.

That said, in regard to *"**To have somebody do something** = to get somebody to do something; a one-off action, something that’s not supposed to take very long."* the sentence ***"Today, Jack had his students ask him questions"*** would most probably mean that the students asked him a lot of question particularly today and it wasn't his initiative to make them do so.

p.s. I would rather say **"ask him a question"**